pybind11 cannot import simplest module
I just started with pybind11 and I wanted to try the minimal example they provide on their page.
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}

I am using visual studio 2022 and I can compile the solution without problem as a dll. This gives me inside the directory x64/Debug the following files
example.dll
example.exp
example.lib
example.pdb

I then go inside the x64/Debug folder and and run python 3.12 (the same version as I used in pybind11), but when I do
>>> import example

I get the following
>>> import example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'

What am I doing wrong?
In the output of the compilation, setting the verbosity to detail, I could get the exact cl.exe arguments which are:
CL.exe /c /IC:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include /I"C:\Users\usr\source\repos\python_cxx_interaction\python_cxx_interaction\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /O2 /Oi /GL /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _WINDLL /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /permissive- /Fo"python_c.f6c111de\x64\Release\\" /Fd"python_c.f6c111de\x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt example.cpp


Try to copy or rename example.dll to example.pyd.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I tried to do this but I get : "Assertion failed! Expression: _PyEval_ThreadsInitialized(). For more information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts"

Cannot reproduce. Everything works as it should on my end after renaming example.dll to example.pyd. You may want to show the exact commands you use to compile and link your module. I compile from the command line like this: cl example.cpp -I"C:\Program Files\Python312\Include" -I"C:\Users\<mydir>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pybind11\include" /EHsc /LD /Zi /link /debug /libpath:"c:\Program Files\Python312\Libs and then copy example.dll example.pyd.

I am compiling with msbuild. Is there a way to find the equivalent cl.exe command?

Also I tried using the same as you cl example.cpp -I"C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include" -I"C:\Users\usr\source\repos\python_cxx_interaction\pybind11-2.12.0\include" /EHsc /LD /Zi /link /debug /libpath:"C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\libs" but I returns a lot of linking errors like example.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyMem_Calloc referenced in function "public: void __thiscall pybind11::detail::instance::allocate_layout(void)" (?allocate_layout@instance@detail@pybind11@@QAEXXZ)

You can look at the build logs

No idea. Perhaps you have more than one version of Python and/or pybind11 installed. I downloaded a Python installer from the official site, and installed pybind11 with pip.

I have added the cl.exe command that is executed when I build the program
